# jquery datepicker change value of input, based on difference between two dates

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 3 input fields

```
<input type="text" name="cust1" id="cust1" size="10" value="" class="inputbox" />
<input type="text" name="cust2" id="cust2" size="10" value="" class="inputbox" />
<input type="text" name="rent_price" id="rent_price" size="10" value="" disabled="disabled" class="inputbox" />
```

jQuery Datepicker

```
$( "input#cust1" ).datepicker();
$( "input#cust2" ).datepicker();
```

And function to change value of input#rent_price:

```
    function setSum()
    {
        var hrs = countHrs();
        $("input#rent_price").attr('value',function(){
           sum = parseInt(BAG_PRICE)*parseInt(hrs);
           if (isNaN(sum))
           {
             sum = '';
             return sum;
           } 
           else 
           {
             return sum;
           }
        });
    }
```

so when i'm writind this:

```
    $( "input#cust1" ).change(setSum());
    $( "input#cust2" ).change(setSum());
```

value of input#rent_price changing only afted refreshing page. If i write alert in `setSum()` it triggers 2 times. So i need some advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use the [datepicker's onClose event](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/#event-onClose):

```
$( "input#cust1" ).datepicker({onClose:function(){ setSum() }});
$( "input#cust2" ).datepicker({onClose:function(){ setSum() }});
```

also when writing code, try not to repeat yourself, editted your function a bit:

```
function setSum()
{
    var sum = parseInt(BAG_PRICE)*parseInt(countHrs());
    if (isNaN(sum)) { sum = '' }
    $("input#rent_price").val(sum);
}
```

Comment: nothing happens. Even `$( "input#cust1" ).datepicker({onClose:function(){ alert('123') }});
` not working

Comment: you have a typo somewhere then; it works fine at http://jsfiddle.net/jftLf/ ; or maybe old version of jquery ui?

Comment: i found it. `$( "input#cust1" ).datepicker();` and then after few lines         `$( "input#cust1" ).datepicker({onClose:function(){ alert('123') }});` my bad :) thx for your help.